# Umbraco 4.5 in a virtual directory with umbracoUseDirectoryUrls

Tags: umbraco, virtual-directory, url-rewriting

I've installed Umbraco 4.5 in a virtual directory on my web server (**server/cms**). When I edit web.config and set `umbracoUseDirectoryUrls = "true"`, the URLs generated don't contain the virtual directory **(i.e. server/page instead of server/cms/page)**.

How can I get `umbracoUseDirectoryUrls` to work with an instance of Umbraco that lives in a virtual directory?

**UPDATE:**
Fixed in [Umbraco 4.5.1](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/48015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Umbraco 4.5. I've logged an [issue](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/workitem/28172) on the [Umbraco codeplex site](http://umbraco.codeplex.com) and a fix is scheduled for release 4.5.1.